# emmeans differences in logistic regression give wrong significance in case of complete separation

Tags: logistic, statistical-significance, lsmeans, separation

Suppose (fictitious example) we have a logistic model for dependent "Happy" (0/1), and factor "Age" ("young", "middle", "old") as independent variable and also factor gender:

$logit = b_0 + b_1middle + b_2old +b_3gender$

For category "young", ALL cases in the sample feel happy, so Happy=1 for each young person  (complete separation). The middle and old aged are happy for say 70 and 50 percent. If tested with a likelihood ratio test ("Anova" from package "car") the regr. effects for the middle and old aged, $b_1$ and $b_2$ are both highly significant. The "glm" function in R uses Wald tests, which yield highly INsignificant results for $b_1$ and $b_2$, due to the "completely" happy young category.

I would like to test the differences in "emmeans" of the age categories, averaged over the two gender categories. I expect the marginal diffence between middle and young to be significant, just like the marginal difference between old and young. However, this is not the case because of the full separation (the p values appear to 0.99). As far as I know, package "emmeans" in R only uses Wald tests. Is there a way to test differences between marginale means in another way (likelihood ratio?) so that the differences mentioned will turn out to be significant, as should be? Thanks for help!

Comment: For a continuous predictor like `Age`, modeling it as continuous instead of binning into categories would be a solution. That should remove the perfect separation problem and allow `emmeans` to make reliable comparisons of predictions at specified ages that are representative of your current age groups. That won't, of course, work for perfect separation due to a predictor that is inherently categorical.

Comment: @EdM thanks for your answer. This was meant as an example only. Say it was marital status instead of age.

Comment: You could look into what the `marginaleffects` package does.  With `type="response"` It will provide you with a 'significant' p-value with a standard error and confidence interval.  I'm not adding as an answer because I don't understand how it does it or the validity of the method.  Have a look at its documentation.